# Second Call crashed of FT_Load_Char free type

Tags: crash, c++builder, freetype

I have a big problem with free type library.
I use FT_Load_Char to get the width of a text to draw.
The first call, all is right, but the second call (the next text to draw), the application crashes.
I use C++ borland and freetype Library (version 2.4.9).
To be more clair, this is my code :

```
   currentLength = 0;

for(unsigned long j = 0; j < Text.size(); j++ )
{
    FT_Error error = FT_Load_Char( m_Face, Text[j], FT_LOAD_RENDER  );
    if ( error )
    {
        continue;  /* ignore errors */
        return 0;
    }
    int  translateX = m_Face->glyph->advance.x >> 6;
    currentLength = currentLength + translateX;
}

if( currentLength > maxLength )
maxLength = currentLength;

FT_Glyph Glyphe;
FT_Get_Glyph(m_Face->glyph, &Glyphe);
FT_Done_Glyph(Glyphe);
FT_Done_Face(m_Face);

return maxLength;
```

What's wrong with my code !!!

Comment: you don't show enough of your code to decide.  Also, what is the crash, what does the debugger show/say.  and what version of C++ Builder and FreeType are you using?

Comment: I have a crash with message : Acces violation, and sometimes files like fobjects, fgrays.. not found
I am using C++ Builder XE and freetype Library 2.4.9.

Comment: In fact, the first text need to get his width, i have no error message, but trying with next text, it is that when i get the crash